# NoClassDefFoundError using with boxable plugin

Tags: pdfbox

I am using boxable plugin with pdfbox and I am trying to create a teble. I am getting error:

```
2015-09-09T10:36:52.453+0200|Severe: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/edit/PDPageContentStream
```

at the line of code:

```
BaseTable table = new BaseTable(yStart,yStartNewPage, bottomMargin, tableWidth, margin, doc, page, true, drawContent);
```

Here is a part from pom.xml, describing the dependencies that I am using:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
      <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.dhorions</groupId>
        <artifactId>boxable</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Is there a bug in current version of dependencies or am I missing something?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
  <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

2.0 is an unreleased version and is in development, and it has a different API. Boxable has its dependencies in its own pom.xml, it is currently requesting 1.8.8. (Which is not the latest version, but I don't think this matters for simple PDF creation)

Comment: Hi Tilman, thanks for the answer... But it does not solve my problem, because I already have a lot of exports to PDF with 2.0 version. It seems that in this case I can not use boxable plugin, and I have to draw tables myself?

Comment: @AndrejK indeed, then you can't use it. What you could do is to modify and build the boxable plugin yourself to be able to work with PDFBox 2.0. Most is just modifying imports, but some calls did also change. If you want to try that route, feel free to ask on the user mailing list if you're searching for a "missing" API.

Comment: Thank you Tilman for the answer. I will try to do it, if I find some spare time :)